# Can't import yml file on Type Script

Tags: typescript, yaml

I'm trying to load an yml file in Type Script, but I get an error like below. How can I solve this problem?

> Cannot find module './locales/en.yml' or its corresponding type declarations.

*index.tsx*

```
import en from './locales/en.yml'
```

*locales/en.yml*

```
Top:
  Title: Sample Title
  Message: Hello! { name }!
```

Comment: Do you have a loader for `yml` files ?  If your import would work at runtime, you just need to add a declaration for `yml` files in a `d.td`: `declare module '*.yml' { const data: string; export default data }`

Comment: Why don't you use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs`